# C# WIndows Phone 8.1 not loading background

Tags: c#, background, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to set one image for all my pages in the solution. I'm working in the `app.xaml.cs` file and I'm trying to adjust the `rootFrame` like this :

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame //THATS WHAT I ADDED
            {
                Background = new ImageBrush()
                {
                    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/wood_background.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)),
                    Stretch = Stretch.None,
                    AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center,
                    AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center
                }
            };
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            //rootFrame = new Frame {CacheSize = 1};

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

however the initialization of the `rootFrame` background doesn't seem to change something at all. My image is located in documents folder of the project under Windows Phone\Assets.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just set it in the XAML?

Comment: Can you try like this: new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wood_background.jpg") - [tripple slash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx)? Is your image's build action set to *content*? Also can you ensure that the page's background is set to transparent, so that it doesn't cover frame's?

Comment: My background was not transparent, thank you a lot for the response,changing it to transparent did the job